# How to upload video file on Mux

Tags: ios, swift, video-upload

I'm trying to upload a recorded video file and regular video file from the photos gallery on Mux server. I am receiving this error message:

```
Error:
The input file was not a valid video or audio file [error type: invalid_input] all the time.
```

I tried uploading via a raw request and Alamofire. Also, I tried encoding the file to MP4 before sending it.

The code looks something like this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

  let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! URL
  AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    multipartFormData.append(videoURL, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mov", mimeType: "video/mov")
  }, with: urlRequest).response { (response) in

  }
}
```

I tried converting `videoURL` to data using:

```
Data(url: videoURL)
InputStream(url: videoURL)
```

I know that in cURL I should have `--data-binary 'Video.mp4'`, which, on Android works, but I don't know how to convert the file to data-binary (byte) on iOS.

Comment: 1.Could you try Data(contentsOf: videoURL).2.Is it possible to not specify mimeType because I doubt if there a mimeType called video/mov

Comment: I tried that already but it didn't pass.

Comment: Have you maybe solved this?